# Почему ломается таблица после отправки данных внутри таблицы?

Tags: php

1) Открываю страницу (t1.php) на ней есть Select option, каждый селект содержит уникальный id, как только я выбрал значение селекта нажимаю кнопку (отправляется Id на сервер с помощью метода POST), далее id передается в sql запрос и строит таблицу по выбранному мною id и попадаю на страницу t2.php

2) на странице t2.php открылась таблица, далее внутри таблицы есть форма, которая отправляет данные на сервер на ту же страницу t2.php и как только данные отправлены, таблица ломается и данные исчезают и остается только макет таблицы + при этом запрос выполняется.

Кто может подсказать почему так происходит ? Может необходимо сохранять id в сессию чтобы значение не терялось при отправке данных с формы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нижняя картинка выводится после нажатия кнопки submit внутри формы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: html можно увидеть?

Comment: @L.Vadim, добавил

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, при повторном вызове страницы t2.php скрипт заново создает таблицу, при этом сперва ее разрушает (drop) или опустошает (truncate). При этом данные, которые должны попадать в табличк,у уже не записываются, так как методом POST ничего не отсылалось.

Есть два возможных решения:

1. вместо повторного вызова t2.php вызывать страничку t3.php, в которой написать необходимый скрипт.
2. если повторный вызов t2.php все же неизбежен, то проверять некий параметр, по которому будет понятно, в какой раз вызывается страница - в первый или повторный.

Но для точного ответа необходим скрипт странички t2.php